Exponential Curve Fitting using Python
I was wondering if anyone knew how to find the values of A and B in Arrhenius equation (=^(−)) using Python. In this equation,  is in Kelvin, and A has the unit of mL/min. We want to obtain a description of the rate as a function for temperature over the range from 0°C to 35°C, under the assumption that we can extrapolate.
Basically, we are trying to find out the activity of the yeast with temperature, but first we have to find A and B. I tried a couple curve fitting techniques but all have failed. My fit was a straight line and my numbers were really off.

This is the code/info given in the image:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as scipy

temperature = np.array([20,25,30,33,35,37,40,45])                  # degrees C
prod_rate = np.array([6.9,9.9,21.2,26.1,32.9,30.4,18.8,18.5])/30   #mL/min

plt.plot(temperature,prod_rate,'ok')
plt.ylabel('Production (mL/min)')
plt.xlabel('Temperature (C)')

this was my best attempt:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as scipy

def arrhenius(T, A, B):
    R = 8.314  # Gas constant, J/(mol·K)
    return A * np.exp(-B / (R * T))

temperature = np.array([20,25,30,33,35,37,40,45])                  # degrees C
prod_rate = np.array([6.9,9.9,21.2,26.1,32.9,30.4,18.8,18.5])/30   #mL/min

plt.plot(temperature, prod_rate, 'ok')
plt.ylabel('Production (mL/min)')
plt.xlabel('Temperature (C)')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(arrhenius, temperature, prod_rate)
print(popt)

A_optimal, B_optimal = popt
fitted_curve = arrhenius(temperature, A_optimal, B_optimal)

plt.plot(temperature, prod_rate, 'ok', label='Data')
plt.plot(temperature, fitted_curve, '-r', label='Fitted Curve')
plt.ylabel('Production (mL/min)')
plt.xlabel('Temperature (°C)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()


print("Optimal value for A:", A_optimal, "mL/min")
print("Optimal value for B:", B_optimal)

This was the image it gave me and the numbers I got:

here is the new graph with Kelvin instead of Celsius:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy as scipy
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def arrhenius(T, A, B):
    R = 8.314  # Gas constant, J/(mol·K)
    return A * np.exp(-B / (R * T))

temperature = np.array([20,25,30,33,35,37,40,45])  
temperature_K = temperature + 273.15                # degrees C
prod_rate = np.array([6.9,9.9,21.2,26.1,32.9,30.4,18.8,18.5])/30   #mL/min


plt.plot(temperature_K, prod_rate, 'ok')
plt.ylabel('Production (mL/min)')
plt.xlabel('Temperature (C)')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(arrhenius, temperature_K, prod_rate)
print(popt)

A_optimal, B_optimal = popt
fitted_curve = arrhenius(temperature_K, A_optimal, B_optimal)

plt.plot(temperature_K, prod_rate, 'ok', label='Data')
plt.plot(temperature_K, fitted_curve, '-r', label='Fitted Curve')
plt.ylabel('Production (mL/min)')
plt.xlabel('Temperature (°C)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

print("Optimal value for A:", A_optimal, "mL/min")
print("Optimal value for B:", B_optimal)

here

When you say "all has failed", what did you try and how did it fail? At least show your best attempt and what output it produced.  B.t.w. you can paste images into a post you don't need to link to them.

this was my best attempt

"this was my best attempt" – I don't see any curve-fitting code in your question.

please look at the new edit that I included in the question. Can't show you my best attempt in the comments, btw thank you for letting me know! ill try pasting them

Thank you for adding that.  I will look at this tomorrow.

In the Arrhenius equation T is supposed to be an absolute temperature (in K). You are using deg C. But I’m not sure that your data will fit it anyway: it shouldn’t tail off at higher temperatures.

Who's to say that your output curve isn't optimal? You only have eight data points. That's not nearly enough (especially with the high variability in your data) to establish a trend.

Your fit is as good as it gets. Your data does not resemble a A exp(-Bx) curve

Also: Arrhenius does not produce a rate in mL/min. It produces a rate constant. Your results are guaranteed to be invalid until this is translated.

when I changed my temperature celsius to kelvin, my fit became a straight line and I'm not sure if that's supposed to happen. ill put the new fit in the question above @Reinderien

actually, now that I'm looking at it, I shouldn't have changed it to degrees K because the data points I was given were in celsius, so that wouldn't help @lastchance

How would I translate it? @Reinderien

The Arrhenius equation DOES depend on absolute temperature in K, so, yes, it should be fitted against that. The fact that it was given to you in deg C is irrelevant. The Arrhenius curve is monotonic increasing; your data is anything but.

when I try to make sure of my A and B values by plugging them into Arrhenius and using one of the temperature points given, my production rate values is kind of off. Im not really sure if my A and B values are correct

A simpler way to find the Arrhenius constants is to plot log(dependent variable) vs 1/T (where T is absolute temperature). If it fitted, that would be a straight line with negative slope. But it won’t fit because the problem lies with your data, not your code. You seem to be killing off yeast at higher temperatures. ( A bit like my bread maker!) Check your data.

your right, in the question it did say that above 35°C the yeast becomes completely unstable, so that's probably why the data is off. but now the fit makes a lot more sense.

Let's assume that your experiment was done wrong. Choose a sub-array to fit, and do it in the logarithmic scale because the linear scales are massive. Do use Kelvin, not Celsius. Here I assume the units of A are arbitrary because the production rate's units have not been corrected.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Gas constant, J/(mol·K); and 0C in K
from scipy.constants import R, zero_Celsius
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

temperature_C = np.array((20, 25, 30, 33, 35, 37, 40, 45))
temperature_K = temperature_C + zero_Celsius
prod_rate_mL_min = np.array((6.9,9.9,21.2,26.1,32.9,30.4,18.8,18.5))/30   # mL/min


def arrhenius(T: np.ndarray, A: float, B: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return A * np.exp(-B/R/T)


def arrhenius_log(T: np.ndarray, logA: float, B: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return logA - B/R/T


# The data are garbage; cut off the last three points during fit
valid_end = -3

# Estimate calculation, partially based on experimental data
B0 = 80_000
logA0 = np.log(
    prod_rate_mL_min[valid_end - 1]
) + B0/R/temperature_K[valid_end - 1]
p0 = logA0, B0

(logA, B), _ = curve_fit(
    f=arrhenius_log, p0=p0,
    xdata=temperature_K[:valid_end],
    ydata=np.log(prod_rate_mL_min[:valid_end]),
)

# Keep A in log space for accuracy's sake
a_pow = np.floor(logA / np.log(10))
a_mantissa = np.exp(logA - a_pow*np.log(10))
print(f'A = {a_mantissa:.6f}e{a_pow:.0f}')
print(f'B = {B:.3f}')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(
    temperature_C[:valid_end], prod_rate_mL_min[:valid_end],
    label='experiment (OK)',
)
ax.scatter(
    temperature_C[valid_end:], prod_rate_mL_min[valid_end:],
    label='experiment (bad)',
)
T_hires = np.linspace(
    start=temperature_K.min(),
    stop=temperature_K.max(),
    num=201,
)
ax.plot(
    T_hires - zero_Celsius,
    np.exp(arrhenius_log(T_hires, *p0)),
    label='guess',
)
ax.plot(
    T_hires - zero_Celsius,
    arrhenius(
        T=T_hires, A=a_mantissa * 10**a_pow, B=B,
    ),
    label='fit',
)
ax.set_xlabel('T (C)')
ax.set_ylabel('Rate (mL/min)')
ax.legend()
plt.show()

A = 6.119210e13
B = 81109.535


Linear-logspace fit
Notice that in log space the expression is linear, so you can reduce to a computationally simpler linear fit that does not require estimates:
import numpy as np

# Gas constant, J/(mol·K); and 0C in K
from scipy.constants import R, zero_Celsius

temperature_C = np.array((20, 25, 30, 33, 35, 37, 40, 45))
temperature_K = temperature_C + zero_Celsius
prod_rate_mL_min = np.array((6.9,9.9,21.2,26.1,32.9,30.4,18.8,18.5))/30   # mL/min

# The data are garbage; cut off the last three points during fit
valid_end = -3

(logA, B), *_ = np.linalg.lstsq(
    a=np.stack((
        np.ones(temperature_K.size + valid_end),
        -1/R/temperature_K[:valid_end],
    ), axis=1),
    b=np.log(prod_rate_mL_min[:valid_end]),
    rcond=None,
)

# Keep A in log space for accuracy's sake
a_pow = np.floor(logA / np.log(10))
a_mantissa = np.exp(logA - a_pow*np.log(10))
print(f'A = {a_mantissa:.6f}e{a_pow:.0f}')
print(f'B = {B:.3f}')

